# How to overload operator for null?

Tags: kotlin, null, operator-overloading

I would like to overload an operator like `invoke` for `null` literal.

For example, so I could writen something like

```
null(1, 2)
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Why would you want to ? What's the use case ?

Comment: I don’t see what the point could be of doing this. You can simply define a top level function with some name.

Comment: @Tenfour04 the point is same as for every overload

Comment: @Tenfour04 are you sure you can't overload on the `null` keyword? https://pl.kotl.in/PIcDxr-5p

Comment: @k314159 I should have said "can't call anything on the `null` keyword *exclusively*". If there's some function intended only to be called on `null` (which still makes no sense to me), then you shouldn't be able to call it on other objects.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I see, sorry I misunderstood your first comment.

Comment: @Tenfour04 ok then, how about `operator fun Nothing?.invoke() = "hi!"` - does this overload only the `null` keyword? I can't think of any expression other than the `null` keyword that has type `Nothing?`.

Comment: That sounds plausible if the compiler will let you do it. It’s impossible to actually have a Nothing to call something on.

Comment: @Tenfour04 but it's possible to have a `Nothing?` (a nullable nothing) and the `null` keyword ends up with that exact type. https://pl.kotl.in/GWIw7HF9c

Comment: @k314159 Yes, you should add an answer.

Comment: @Tenfour04 you forgot about polymorphism! I can have a set of functions with the same name which work for different types and also allow `null` value.

Comment: I thought you specifically wanted something that could be called only on null and nothing else. Basically a function named null.

Comment: Yes, I wanted it, but as overloading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't advise overloading anything on the `null` literal, as it would cause too much confusion and would have no real-world use case.

However, technically, it's possible:

```
operator fun Nothing?.invoke() = "hi!"

fun main() {
    println(null())  // Works, prints "hi!"

    val x = null
    println(x())  // Also works.

    val y: String? = null
    //println(y())  // compilation error

    val z: String = ""
    //println(z())  // also compilation error
}
```

It makes use of the fact that the `null` keyword has the nullable type `Nothing?`.